# my react native component is not displaying more than 1 complaint

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I am working on a screen which takes route parameters from my prev screen as navigated to it, however it is only displaying the first complaint and never shows any others added ones idk what's causing the issue here's the code:

```
const ECScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { imageUri, complaintDate, complaintId } = route.params;

  const [complaints, setComplaints] = useState([]);
 // Function to add a new complaint to the complaints state
 const addNewComplaint = (newComplaint) => {
  setComplaints((prevComplaints) => [...prevComplaints, newComplaint]);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (imageUri && complaintDate) {
    const newComplaint = {
      id: complaints.length + 1,
      imageUri: imageUri,
      date: complaintDate,
      status: 'Pending',
    };
    addNewComplaint(newComplaint);
  }
}, [imageUri, complaintDate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyImage = async () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('imagefile', {
        uri: imageUri,
        type: 'image/jpeg', // Replace with the appropriate image type
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });

      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:5000/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        });
        const data = await response.text();
    
        console.log('Received value text:', data);
    
        if (data === 'Garbage') {
          // Update the complaint status based on the response
          setComplaints((prevComplaints) => {
            return prevComplaints.map((complaint) =>
              complaint.imageUri === imageUri ? { ...complaint, status: 'Verified' } : complaint
            );
          });
        } else {
          // Image is not garbage, set status to 'Invalid'
          setComplaints((prevComplaints) => {
            return prevComplaints.map((complaint) =>
              complaint.imageUri === imageUri ? { ...complaint, status: 'Invalid' } : complaint
            );
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending request to Flask:', error);
      }
    };
    if (imageUri) {
      verifyImage();
    }
  }, [imageUri]);

  
  const handleDeleteButtonPress = (id) => {
    // Remove the complaint with the given ID
    const updatedComplaints = complaints.filter((complaint) => complaint.id !== id);
    setComplaints(updatedComplaints);
    navigation.navigate('Manage Complaint Screen', {
      imageUri: null, // Set imageUri to null
      complaintDate: complaint.date,
      complaintId: id,
      complaints: updatedComplaints,
    });
  };

  const complaint = complaints.find((complaint) => complaint.imageUri === imageUri);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {complaints.length > 0 ? (
        complaints.map((complaint) => (
          <View key={complaint.id} style={styles.complaintContainer}>
            {complaint.imageUri ? (
              <Image source={{ uri: complaint.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri:
                    'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1198347486/vector/photo-camera-vector-icon-with-hand-drawn-doodle-style-isolated-on-white.jpg?s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=bfrS3E5e29kK33aRkVMN3-RdAOD7g9JvFEG52_vOfZ8=',
                }}
                style={styles.image}
              />
            )}
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.dateText}>Date: {complaint.date}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.statusText}>Status: {complaint.status}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.deleteButton}
              onPress={() => handleDeleteButtonPress(complaint.id)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.icon}>x</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.noComplaintsText}>No complaints registered</Text>
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.addButton}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Register Complaint Screen')
        }
      >
        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Im a beginner and I wrote this code in chunks and compiled it I think I am unable to react to the point what s causing the issue please help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this function on useEffect with empty dependency array which is called on mounting of component and initially complaints is also empty.

So `[...complaints, newComplaint]` will be equal to single value that is your `newComplaint`.

Can you please tell on which variable you want your `complaints` to be updated?

Comment: i want the complaints to add the prev registered and newly registered ones as allComplaints and display them on screen I tried this as well but Im still encountring the same problem, only 1 complaint is displayed 'useEffect(() => {
    if (imageUri && complaintDate) {
      setComplaints(prevComplaints => [
        ...prevComplaints,
        {
          id: prevComplaints.length + 1,
          imageUri: imageUri,
          date: complaintDate,
          status: 'Pending',
        }
      ]);
    }
  }, [imageUri, complaintDate]);'